# how to pass json array in select query using hibernate in spring boot

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

```
timings:[{"day": "Monday", "endTime": "18:00", "startTime": "09:00"}, 
         {"day": "Tuesday", "endTime": "18:00", "startTime": "09:00"}, 
         {"day": "Wednesday", "endTime": "18:00", "startTime": "09:00"}, 
         {"day": "Thursday", "endTime": "18:00", "startTime": "09:00"}, 
         {"day": "Friday", "endTime": "18:00", "startTime": "09:00"}]
```

this is my json array i need to get hibernate query on startTime where day=:day(ex:Monday)

```
SELECT id, elements ->> 'endTime' 
FROM work_shift, jsonb_array_elements(timings) elements 
WHERE elements ->> 'day' = 'Monday'
```

i tried this but hibernate is not supporting this

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! "i tried this but hibernate is not supporting this"  - can you show what exactly you've tried and what was the problem?

Comment: expecting OPEN, found '-' near line 1, column 21 [select id, elements ->'endTime' FROM com.smac.settingsService.employee.Employee, jsonb_array_elements(timings) elements WHERE elements ->'day'='Monday']   i am getting this while exceucting the above mentioned query.

Comment: how to write hibernate select query using jsonb array. when i pass day i need to get endTime of that day in timings (column) (jsonb array object)      my json object like this timings:[{"day":"Monday",startTime:"18:00","endTime":"19:00"}]

Comment: Are you creating this query with `entityManager.createNativeQuery`?

Comment: @ChristianBeikov nativequery i am creating

Comment: Try using `json_extract_path_text(elements, 'endTime')` and  `json_extract_path_text(elements, 'day')` instead of `elements ->> 'endTime'` and  `elements ->> 'day'`

Comment: @ChristianBeikov ya i tried this but spring boot not taking that '->>' is there any another way for that